# Docker zero down time

Tags: docker, nginx, swarm

I want to have to achieve zero downtime. I have created a service with 5 replicas and deploy into the stack then I want to update the existing service with some new changes and deploy into the stack with zero downtime.

`version: "3"
services:
  hello-html:
    image: hello-html:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:80
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: overlay`

Answer (score 0):

Use Kubernetes container as a services (CAAS) to do update the application with zero downtime

Answer (score 0):

Use docker service update - refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_update/ for syntax.

And use docker service ls to get a list of your services and know which one to update.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set up the following options for my services:

```
--update-order start-first
--update-delay 1m # depends how long your tasks needs untill it's ready
```

I also had to implement a [HealthCheck](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck) for my api with:

```
start period 1m
```

This way docker doesn't redirect traffic before the task is ready.

For example:

```
HEALTHCHECK --interval=5m --timeout=3s --start-period=1m \
  CMD curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1
```